# How can i display tokens with html tags?

Tags: 8, tokens

On assigning tokens(both custom and exisiting tokens) with values like

```
$replacements[$original] = "<b>Hello</b>";
```

and then using that token either in full html or any other text format(all the text formats) it displays on the screen `<b>Hello</b>` i.e actual tags are being rendered instead of **Hello** . Same is happening with other html tags i.e entire `<div> <p>` all the html tags get display. 
This although does not happen in Drupal 7.

Is there any configuration i am missing? How to render html values properly using tokens?

Answer (score 12):

Try this one -

```
$replacements[$original] = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create("<b>Hello</b>");
```

Helpful links:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Markup.php/class/Markup/8.2.x

http://www.drupaldump.com/drupal-8-how-have-custom-tokens-html-them-properly-replaced

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to access the token under the html tag then another way is that, you just create token as

```
  switch ($name) {
   case 'custom_token':
     $text = 'Hello World!';
     $replacements[$original] = $text;
   break;
```

After, into the body part you can access this token with html tags.

```
(i.e) <b>[custom:custom_token]</b>
```

even i used it as screen shot
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

After you replace, you have to use:
'htmlspecialchars_decode' like this:

```
$body = htmlspecialchars_decode($token->replace($body, $data));
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is it will decode the entire $body which may be undesirable. Ideally the solution would only affect the tokenized values.